# how to create a seasonal chart in superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to make a seasonal chart, that is, a chart where the horizontal coordinate is only from January 1 to December 31, but where I can select the year on the label.
Just like this chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Superset v1.5.0, you can enable `GENERIC_CHART_AXES` flag in config.py, which will allow to set non-timeseries column as X-Axis in Line Chart.

So keep day as X-Axis and Year as 'Group By' to create the chart you are looking for.

PS: Mixed Timeseries does not support this yet, so you can't have secondary Y-axis as you have shared in the image.